# apple configurator for new Files application

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, apple-configurator

I would like to push to our users a mobileconfig built using Apple Configurator to include a configuration to our WebDav folder using the new **Files** app. Is this possible.  Many of our corporate users use dropbox because Webdav is not native way to store files in the cloud.  This could help resolve the issue and provide WebDav access to corporate files stored in the cloud.

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: The files app does not support WebDAV natively. You would need to write an app that provides an [`NSFileProvider`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider) interface to your WebDAV service.

Comment: Thanks! I wish it was simpler but will crank up the Xcode machine then! Happy Holidays Paul.